# Pivot a Date Range into multiple rows

Tags: sql, pivot, vertica

I have a table T in this format:

| ClientName | StartMonth | EndingMonth |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | Dec 2018 | Jan 2021 |

I want the output of my query to be:

| ClientName | MonthRange | Year # |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | Dec 2018-Nov 2019 | 1 |
| X | Dec 2019-Nov 2020 | 2 |
| X | Dec 2020-Nov 2021 | 3 |

Can someone help me what is the best way to tackle this problem?

Comment: Hey, its Vertica. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: If you change your StartMonth and EndingMonth to datetime value , it is easy to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH
indata(clientname,startmonth,endmonth) AS(
  SELECT 'x',DATE '2018-12-01', DATE '2021-01-01'
)
,
-- a series of at least 3 integers - no other way ...
y(y) AS (
          SELECT 1
UNION ALL SELECT 2
UNION ALL SELECT 3
UNION ALL SELECT 4
)
SELECT 
  clientname
,  TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(startmonth,(y-1)*12),'Mon-YYYY')
 ||'-'
 ||TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(startmonth,(y-1)*12+11),'Mon-YYYY') AS monthrange
, y AS "year#"
FROM indata CROSS JOIN y
WHERE ADD_MONTHS(startmonth,(y-1)*12) <= endmonth
ORDER BY y;

clientname|monthrange       |year#
x         |Dec-2018-Nov-2019|    1
x         |Dec-2019-Nov-2020|    2
x         |Dec-2020-Nov-2021|    3
```

Comment: what is indata?

Comment: indata is a Common Table expression ; the `WITH` clause is used to contain one or more Common Table expressions; `WITH tb1 AS (fullselect), tb2 AS (fullselect) SELECT ....`. I have 2 Common Table expressions here, indata (your input data) and y for the years.